# 230VAC to 30VDC/6A power supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

I am working on a lab bench power supply capable of 30V at 5A. It is a linear PSU so therefore i will need 30VDC to feed into a regulator (5x LT3080 in parallel). I think that 1A is enough for the control circuit, so in order to deliver 5A at the output, the first "stage" of my power supply will be to convert 230VAC @ 50Hz down to 30V capable of delivering 6A with low ripple (1A for the control circuitry).

This is the circuit i have so far:
[image: 230VAC to 30VDC]
My theory is as follows,

1. The transformer lowers the mains voltage to 30V RMS
2. The diode bridge rectifies the 30V RMS to 42.4VDC with two big capacitors to filter the ripple.
3. The RC circuit, made from R1 and C1, filters the ripple with a cutoff frequency of around 0.3Hz. This voltage is then fed into the base of Q1 (which can deliver more current than the RC filter), which creates an emitter-follower capacitance multiplier.
4. The driving circuit for Q2 is inspired from the LM78xx simplified schematic. Q3 is added for increased current capability, and will turn on when a current of 133mA flows through R2 and R3 which will create a 1V voltage drop (base-emitter saturation voltage of Q3 is around 1V).
5. Q2 will be driven by the op amp such that it's inverting input will have the same value as the non-inverting. This should create 30V at the emitter of Q2.

R8 is just a potentiometer for calibration. The value of R5 and R8 should be 10k as the voltage divider will have an output voltage of 10V at an input of 30V. ZD1 is a 10V diode.

My question is if i have missed anything? Do you have any recommendations for the design?

Comment: A couple of observations: (1) Why not power the op-amp from left of R2/R3? That will give you additional headroom. (2) 40 V x 5 A = 200 W dissipation at lowest voltage setting. That's a big ask for a transistor to dissipate. Any commercial 3 A linear bench supplies that I've looked at had an array of transistors in parallel.

Comment: Your capacitance multiplier won’t work well with the Darlington in saturation. Get a simulator and simulate it. These sort of questions are usually solved by doing a simulation but, maybe you are hoping that some kind person will do this for you?

Comment: If you don't want to calibrate the voltage based on zener operation and even then have it vary somewhat under load, consider using a TL431 or similar as reference. 0.5% versions about as cheap as 2%. Arguably it doesn't matter as R8 sets the voltage and a voltmeter tells you the result, but a reasonably stable and accurate reference is easy and cheap.

Comment: @Andyaka i do not (yet) have the transistors to test the circuit at high current draws, but at low ones it does work in reality. I have tried simulating it in circuitLab multiple times and it seems to work up to around 7A. I don't really understand why the darlington would be in saturation as Vc>Vb>Ve (active). Can you please elaborate on this? And if it really is in saturation, how could this be solved?

Comment: The current it works up to is immaterial - you need to test it as a capacitance multiplier to see that it will be ineffective because, the darlington is fully on and saturated.